# Why is my refrigerator cooling to the point that contents freeze?

Tags: refrigerator

My fridge has been getting too cold and things in the fridge are freezing. The water dispenser won't work because the water is frozen in the lines. Sometimes fruits or drinks are frozen or slushy.

I tried to check the damper door and it seems to work fine. The only way I can really test is with a power cycle. When it gets too cold, I see that the damper is open. I power cycle the fridge and when it power back on, the damper closes. Interestingly it goes back to a normal temperature and everything is fine for a couple days. Then it happens again.

I bought a couple replacement thermistors and I was going to try to swap it out. (I tried testing the resistance but my multimeter can't get a solid reading out of it). But now I'm wondering if it could be the logic board because a really brief power reset makes it go back to normal.

It's a whirlpool if that helps, with the two doors on top and freezer below, and the temp settings on the top are digital but just have a setting of 1 to 7 with 4 being the recommended setting.

Comment: Get a decent thermometer and figure out how cold the freezer and refrigerator get when "normal" and "problem". A residential freezer should get close to 0F, and refrigerator between 35 F and 40 F. Knowing whether the freezer is right normally and whether the freezer is colder or warmer when the refrigerator is too cold may be a big clue, depending on the particular design, as most (not all) have a single cycle running both sections.

Comment: Whirlpool makes a lot of fridges, so how about a specific model number? Maybe even look up whatever documentation you can find online and include links. Some might consider that a courtesy to those willing to help you for free.

Comment: Airflow within the refrigerator can be an issue. If you've got tall/blocky items disrupting the normal cooling airflow, you can get overcold spots away from temperature sensor.

Comment: What do you have it set to?

Comment: Check the fan in the freezer, failure of that fan (iced or broken) could cause the refrigerator to get extra cold.  This happens because the refrigerant is not vaporize as much as it should be in the freezer and gets vaporized in the refrigerator section instead giving it more capacity